# Samba Access Wrapper

Tags: python, networking

I created a Python module to access Samba shares some time ago, using Mike Teos' SMB module as some kind of a base to it. It is mostly a wrapper, but as I said, I wrote it some time ago and would appreciate feedback on readability, usability and modularity of this module.

**ServerAccess.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__DEBUG__=9

from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
from smb.base import SharedDevice
from smb.base import SharedFile

import tempfile
from socket import getfqdn
from Networking import resolveNetworkTuple

import logging
import sys
import os       # Path operations


class ServerException(Exception):
        pass

class ServerAccess:
        """
            Description: ServerAccess Class and File Handler
        """
        def __init__(self,username, password, client_name=None, server_name=None, server_ip=None, shared_folder=None, timeout=5):
                self.__logger=logging.getLogger("Notenverwaltung")
                # use_ntlm_v2 must be passed as named argument
                self.__logger.debug("   username      = %s"%(username))
                self.__logger.debug("   password      = xxxxxxxxxx")
                self.__logger.debug("   client_name   = %s"%(client_name))
                self.__logger.debug("   server_name   = %s"%(server_name))
                self.__logger.debug("   server_ip     = %s"%(server_ip))
                self.__logger.debug("   shared_folder = %s"%(shared_folder))
                self.__logger.debug("   timeout       = %s"%(timeout))

                self.__user=username
                self.__pass=password

                if client_name==None:
                        client_name=getfqdn()
                self.__client=client_name
                if server_ip:
                        server_ip, server_name=resolveNetworkTuple("%s"%server_ip)
                elif server_name:
                        server_ip, server_name=resolveNetworkTuple("%s"%server_name)
                self.__server=server_name
                self.__serverIP=server_ip

                self.__port=445
                self.__timeout=timeout
                self.conn = SMBConnection(username, password, client_name, server_name, use_ntlm_v2 = False)
                self.shared = shared_folder

                self.__logger.debug("Constructor connects to: \n%s"%self)
                assert self.conn.connect("%s"%self.__serverIP, self.__port, timeout=self.__timeout)

        def __del__(self):
                try:
                   self.conn.close()
                except:
                   pass

        def __str__(self):
                result=("\n<Server Access Object>")
                result+=("\n   <user>%s</user>"%self.__user)
                result+=("\n   <pass>xxxxxx</pass>")
                result+=("\n   <client>%s</client>"%self.__client)
                result+=("\n   <server>%s</server>"%self.__server)
                result+=("\n   <serverIP>%s</serverIP>"%self.__serverIP)
                result+=("\n   <port>%s</port>"%self.__port)
                if self.shared:
                        result+=("\n   <share>%s</share>"%self.shared)
                result+=("\n   <timeout>%s</timeout>"%self.__timeout)
                result+=("\n</Server Access Object>")
                return result

        def __getHost(self): return self.__server
        def __setHost(self, value): self.__server=value
        Host=property(__getHost, __setHost)

        def listFiles(self, share=None, path=""):
                if share!=None:
                         return self.conn.listPath(share, path, 55)
                elif self.shared:
                         return self.conn.listPath(self.shared, path, 55)

        def listDirectories(self, share=None, path=""):
                return ([ __dir for __dir in self.listFiles(share, path) if __dir.isDirectory])

        def listShares(self):
                self.__ServerShares=[]
                if self.conn:
                         for dev in self.conn.listShares(self.__timeout):
                              if dev.type == SharedDevice.DISK_TREE:
                                    self.__ServerShares.append(dev.name)
                return self.__ServerShares

        def getFile(self, filename, share=None):
                file_obj = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
                if share==None: share=self.shared
                file_attributes, filesize = self.conn.retrieveFile(share,filename,file_obj)
                # Otherwise all we get is crap
                file_obj.seek(0,0)

                return file_obj

        def writeFile(self,file_obj,filename, share=None):
                if share!=None: self.shared=share
                filename=os.path.normpath(filename)
                filename=filename.replace('\\','/')

                __curr_dir=""
                dirnames=os.path.split(filename)

                for __dir_idx in range(len(dirnames[:-1])):
                        __curr_dir="%s%s/"%(__curr_dir, dirnames[__dir_idx])
                        self.writeDirectory("%s"%__curr_dir)

                try:
                        self.conn.storeFile(self.shared,"%s"%filename,file_obj)
                except:
                        raise ServerException("Creating File <%s> failed using %s"%(filename, self))

        def writeDirectory(self, dirpath, share=None):
                if share!=None: self.shared=share

                # Check if Path already exists
                if len(self.conn.listPath(self.shared, dirpath))!=0:
                        return
                try:
                        self.conn.createDirectory(self.shared, dirpath)
                except Exception as ex:
                        raise ServerException("Creating Directory <%s> failed using %s"%(dirpath, self))

        def moveFile(self,filename1,filename2):
                file_obj = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
                file_attributes, filesize = self.conn.retrieveFile(self.shared,filename,file_obj)
                self.conn.storeFile(self.shared,filename2,file_obj)
                file_obj.close()
                self.conn.deleteFiles(self.shared,filename1)

        def deleteFile(self, filename, share=None):
                if share!=None: self.shared=share
                self.conn.deleteFiles(self.shared,filename)

        def deleteDirectory(self, dirpath, share=None):
                if share!=None: self.shared=share

                # Check if Path already exists
                if len(self.conn.listPath(self.shared, dirpath))!=0:
                        return
                try:
                        self.conn.deleteDirectory(self.shared, dirpath)
                except:
                        raise ServerException("Deletion of Directory <%s> failed using %s"%(dirpath, self))

if __name__=="__main__":

   import argparse, getpass
   import Networking, socket

   logger=logging.getLogger("ServerAccess")

   parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Server Access Library")

   parser.add_argument('--host', type=str, required=True, dest='host')
   parser.add_argument('-u', '--user', type=str, required=True, dest='user')
   parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', dest='usePW', default=False, action='store_true')
   parser.add_argument('-s', '--share', type=str, dest='share', default="")

   args=parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

   hostIP, hostName=Networking.resolveNetworkTuple(args.host)

   logger.debug("%s trying to connect to %s"%(socket.getfqdn(), hostName))
   if args.usePW:
      password=getpass.getpass("Please enter password: ")

   if args.share!="":
      app=ServerAccess(args.user, password, socket.getfqdn(), hostName, hostIP, args.share)
      print args.share
      for shareFile in app.listFiles(args.share):
         if not shareFile.filename in [".",".."]:
            logger.debug(" %s"%shareFile.filename)
   else:
      app=ServerAccess(args.user, password, server_name=hostName, server_ip=hostIP)

      for share in app.listShares():
         logger.debug(share)
         for shareFile in app.listFiles(share):
            if not shareFile.filename in [".",".."]:
               logger.debug(" %s"%shareFile.filename
```

Networking.py is a module I wrote myself as well:

**Networking.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket, re, time
import logging

from errno import ECONNREFUSED

__DEBUG__=1

logger=logging.getLogger("Networking")

def resolveNetworkTuple(addr):
      '''
      Resolve addr to receive IP Address and Hostname
      '''

      IP=""
      Hostname=""

      logger.info("Trying to resolve %s ... "%addr)
      if re.compile("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$").match(addr):
              # We got an IP
              logger.info("Read address [%s] as IP"%addr)
              IP=addr
              Hostname=socket.gethostbyaddr(IP)[0]
      else:
              # We got a Hostname
              Hostname=addr

              logger.info("Read address [%s] as Hostname"%Hostname)
              #we resolve until we get info or max retries reached
              __tries=5
              while IP=="" and __tries>0:
                      try:
                              logger.info("Resolve %s:  %s"%(Hostname, socket.getaddrinfo(Hostname, 80, socket.AF_INET)))
                              IP=socket.getaddrinfo(Hostname, 80, socket.AF_INET)[0][4][0]
                      except:
                              IP=""
                      finally:
                              time.sleep(2)
                              __tries=__tries-1

      logger.info("Result: %s | %s (IP, Hostname)"%(IP, Hostname))
      return IP, Hostname
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please stick to 4 spaces for indentation. It's the Python standard and makes things much easier to read. You can read about this and many other Python style notes in the [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), I highly recommend it for readability.

Instead of `== None` it's more Pythonic to use `is None`.

You're also using the old `%` string formatting, use the newer one instead as it makes things easier and more readable. The new way is `str.format`, here's an example:

```
self.__logger.debug("Constructor connects to: \n%s"%self)
```

turns into

```
self.__logger.debug("Constructor connects to: \n{}".format(self))
```

Those `{}` get replaced by the parameters passed to `format`. It might not seem much use in this case, but later when you have multiple parameters it'll be much better, so it's good to be used to it.

It's great to see a `__str__`, implementing them is good practice. You can make your life a whole lot easier though by using implicit string concatenation. If two string literals are placed side by side with nothing but space between them, Python just concatenates them observe:

```
>>> "concat" "enation"
'concatenation'
>>> "concat"            "enation"
'concatenation'
```

This can work over multiple lines, if you put parentheses around the full expression:

```
>>> ("concat"
 "enation")
'concatenation'
>>> ("concat"
 "ena"
     "tio"
 "n")
'concatenation'
```

Of course this can make your `result` making much easier:

```
def __str__(self):
    result = ("\n"
              "\n   %s"%self.__user
              "\n   xxxxxx"
              "\n   %s"%self.__client
              "\n   %s"%self.__server
              "\n   %s"%self.__serverIP
              "\n   %s"%self.__port)
    if self.shared:
        result+=("\n   %s"%self.shared)
    result += ("\n   %s"%self.__timeout
               "\n")
    return result
```

Avoid using bare `try except`s! You do it a few times. This will ignore any exceptions that arise. Even something like a `SystemExit` or a `KeyboardInterrupt`. You should at least use `except Exception:` in order to ignore those two cases. It would also be a good idea to log what exceptions occurred, as it could have been one you weren't anticipating. If you don't log unanticipated exceptions then you'll never know what they are, nor will you know how to fix the bug causing them.

You should *always* put `import` statements at the top of the file, so that people know where to look for them when they see you using them. Otherwise people will get confused when they scroll to the top and don't see them anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, i will update the question as soon as i reworked the code for another review round.

Comment: @R4PH43L Glad to help. When you want to get another review, make sure you ask a new question and then just link to this one explaining it's a follow up.

Comment: Is it better to use `property` or `__getattr__` `__setattr__`?

Comment: @R4PH43L They're for different purposes. `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` modify how your class deals with *all* attributes when using dot syntax like `class.attribute`, whereas `property` allows you to set behaviour for one specific attribute.

Comment: So there wouldn't be a problem in overloading __getattr__/__setattr__, or would it? (As long as the time when they are called are taken into account)

Comment: @R4PH43L Python doesn't technically allow overloading, at least not in the Java way I'm familiar with. To overload in Python you need to have just one function test the parameters and perform some code based on what they return. I'm not sure that's what you really want, if you want to talk about it more we could move to an SE chat chatroom to talk about itinstead.